# HTML CSS Positioning 4 divs horizontally

Tags: html, css

Having some trouble with positioning elements on a site. I set up the site container layout with 4 divs that I want to line up horizontally, but can't get them to do it. They are labeled "left-gutter", "image-column", "text column", & "right-gutter"-- all wrapped in a background div. I've tried positioning them with CSS using float:left and display:inline-block. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

https://github.com/ajhalbrook/Sample

Here is what it should look like:
[image]

Comment: can you post this html and css on jsfiddle.net? you are more likely to get help.

Comment: I believe @Dejan.S meant "Can you post a _link_ to a jsfiddle with your html and css?" It would also help if you include a very simplified version of the code in your question.

Comment: It appears that you actually want to line-them-up _vertically_ (making sure that they are of equal width in the process).  Or do you want to line them up horizontally (not what is shown in your picture)?

Comment: Could you put the relevant code in your post? Code at github could change over time, and we won't know what to look for.

Comment: I copied it to jsfiddle but am having trouble with the images working correctly

Comment: dont mind the images, just put empty space there.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/yv6NW/

Comment: tried with the kittens http://jsfiddle.net/TRTWy/

Comment: @chipman I love seeing the kittens, but go ahead and use the one I just posted.  It uses your images taken from the github "raw" urls.

Comment: OK, cool thanks. Yeah I was trying that but jsfiddle was giving me an error message. ;)

Comment: When using Github, this: `https://github.com/ajhalbrook/Sample/blob/master/images/image1.jpg` is a webpage.  And this: `https://raw.github.com/ajhalbrook/Sample/master/images/image1.jpg` is the url of an image. Notice the different subdomain (none or www versus raw)

Comment: Right, I began to use the "raw" version and jsfiddle was telling me it wouldn't work and throwing up this error message "Github is not a CDN, using it as such will cause issues with loading the file. Do you still wish to it?"

Comment: @chipman look at my answer maybe it will help you?

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
position: absolute;
left: xx px;
top: xxx px:
```

for each div.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want divs to float next to each other, you need to place them at same root level, i.e

div1 - div2 - div3 - div4

In you case, the code on github shows

```
"left-gutter" is parent having childs as
 |-- "right-gutter" and
 |-- "image-column"(which further has child)
      |-- "text column"
```

Your code should be of

```
wrapper
|-- "left-gutter"
|-- "right-gutter"
|-- "image-column"
|-- "text-column"
```

Comment: There is content within each of the child divs that need to be positioned separately relative to the div they're in, that is why I did that. I have all the divs wrapped in the "background" div. Will this not work? Should I have it set up completely different?

Comment: After seeing the screen shot I'm bit confused.

In question description you wrote, you want to align the divs horizontally, but in the screen shot you have shown the divs aligned vertically. Please describe, how exactly you want to align the divs?